# How can I completely disable transition for popover?

Tags: blueprintjs

I know I can use `hoverOpenDelay={0}` and `hoverCloseDelay={0}`, but there is still a 100ms opacity transition on the popover container that I'm unable to change, as far as I can tell. I would like to remove this transition so the popover appears instantly.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

This is quite hard. Blueprint uses the `react-addons-css-transition-group` library that adds `-enter`, `-appear`, `-leave`, `-enter-active`, `-appear-active`, `-leave-active` suffixes to some class names of elements that need to be animated. In your case you probably need to manually override the overlay styles e.g. something like this:

```
.pt-overlay-enter,
.pt-overlay-appear {
  opacity: 0;
}

.pt-overlay-enter-active,
.pt-overlay-appear-active {
  opacity: 1;
  transition-property: opacity;
  // `step` didn't work cross browser for me
  transition-timing-function: ease; 
  // i've found 0ms is causes react-addons-css-transition-group to fire events unreliable on certain browsers
  transition-duration: 1ms
  transition-delay: 0;
}
```

Of course, you'll want to narrow the scope of these rules to only to apply to popovers for which you want to remove animations.

If you want to see exactly what `blueprint` is doing to style the animation lifecycle classes, check out the styles [here](https://github.com/palantir/blueprint/blob/master/packages/core/src/common/_react-transition.scss). The `react-transition` mixin is used [here](https://github.com/palantir/blueprint/blob/823ff7230c6d3d83f6209c914092f81025d0d883/packages/core/src/components/overlay/_overlay.scss#L63) (among other places).

Comment: Yeah, the problem is that setting the transition duration to 0ms, like you mentioned, causes problems with the popover reliably showing or hiding. This seems like a pretty poor way of handling things. Is there any way to just disable the react-addons-css-transition for this component or something? The 1ms delay is perceivable.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. And yes, `1ms` was good enough for me but there certainly is a frame or so of animation. The library is pretty ingrained into Blueprint but should be easy to expose a prop to users to disable animations on a per-component basis. This hasn't been a _huge_ issue yet for most users but I'd encourage you to file a ticket on the Github repo.